# What is the equivalent of Android Webview In the ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, webview, ionic-framework

I created a IONIC/Angular JS application ; and I want to load a web page on it as is done with Android WebView; that is to say, display my web page in a division of my ionic application.  So the question is, is there a IONIC  component that can do this?

Comment: Ionic is a HTML/JavaScript/CSS framework more specifically a UI framework where as Angular JS is the Model/View framework for interacting with the UI. Cordova is the WebView framework that allow you to run Web apps. So what you need is Cordova/phonegap for running your Ionic/Angular app.

Comment: Thanks frank, I know that. Really, what i want to is to load an external web page in a division of my ionic application. Please look at this example : [link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm); it's an android example.

Comment: I am not getting your point. Do you want to load an external webpage or you want to load an Ionic web app in the webview?. If you want to load an the external webpage within your `Cordova based Ionic application`, then you can use the `in-app browser plugin` to load external webpages.

Comment: [Inappbrowser Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)

Comment: The role of inAppBrowser is to open from my ionic App a given link in another browser tab . But I want to avoid that: this link will open in another tab; I want it opens in my Ionic application exactly like this : [link](tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm). But if this is not feasible with Ionic , I 'll just use  **" inAppBrowser "**.

Comment: Try to use `window.location = "http://www.website.com";` or try `window.location.assign("http://www.website.com")` to load it in the same webview as the Ionic App.

Comment: Thank you Frank :) I think that's the good way to do.

Answer (score 13):

I know you posted this question a while ago. I had the same need to embed a webpage inside my ionic page and the solution I found was to add an iframe tag. Set the source to go to the link you want to embed.The iframe will contain the webpage inside the application. you can even create a controller to add further functionality. See my code below:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class= 'padding has-subheader'>
    <iframe class= 'webPage' name= "eventsPage" src="http://www.algonquincollege.com/studentsupportservices/events/">
   </iframe>
  </ion-content></ion-view>
```

For styling you will need to target a div with the class scroll that gets created automatically by ionic. For example, I wanted to to make the webpage fill a width of 90%. see code below:

```
ion-content div.scroll{
  height: 90%; }

.webPage{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #EAAB00;
  padding: 1rem;}
```

Hope this helps.
full details here: http://mobileapplicationsdesigndevelopment.blogspot.ca/

Comment: i didn't try Nehmat's solution, but this worked for me, so i wanted to share... https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/

Comment: Great! however, some javascript in the embedded website cannot be executed, it shows error message ```Blocked a frame with origin "http://xxxx" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.``` Any idea how to solve this problem? (I've already set up whitelist and access in config.xml)

Comment: @nehmat-gereige You're a life savior !! Thanks alot

Comment: hi @Kevin , do you set `InAppBrowser` plugin? i have same problem and remove the `InAppBrowser` plugin relsolve the frame problem